# How do increment an integer that is part of a string at each iteration of loop

Tags: c#

i have a string like this S02E01 and now i want to run it through a loop like 20 times but at each iteration i want to increment the number after 'E' so that we have for example S02E01,S02E02,S02E03 ..S0210,...S02E20. Please help me.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] of what you have tried. Also, have you considered storing the number in its own variable and creating the string from that? Take a look at [ask] and the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really simple by using some string functions: [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_), [PadLeft](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-padleft-method/) or [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros)

```
string mystring = "S02E00";

var template = mystring.Substring(0, mystring.Length - 2);//template =  "S02E"
for(int i = 0;i <= 20; i++)
{
    var result = template + i.ToString("00");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

you could use PadLeft too => `var result = template + i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');`

Comment: thanks very much.I'm actually trying to create a program to duplicate tv shows download links from a certain website cus i will bulk download them using IDM and incrementing the episode numbers was my challenge. But thanks to you i dont have to change the episode numbers manually using notepad but i can now do it in c#.